# Extract information from XCUIElement

Tags: xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

If I'm trying to write a generic test that isn't dependent on labels or other value-specific elements, how do I get that information?  Like if I were to tap a tableview cell and need some information from there later.  Like to identify which cell was tapped.  How could I grab a label from it using an XCUIElement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you can extract from `XCUIElement` is limited to those in the [`XCUIElementAttributes` protocol](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Protocols/XCUIElementAttributes.html). The most notable of these are, `identifier`, `value`, and `title`.

You can set the `identifier` via `-accessibilityIdentifier` in your production code. The `value` property can be set from a couple of different paths, but it's usually the the active state of a control. For example, a picker's selected element.

You can try using the Accessibility Inspector to see what's already set on your element and then using a query to find that element.

Comment: I never can get an actual value for some reason.  I keep trying things like this:

app.tables.elementBoundByIndex(0).cells.elementBoundByIndex(3).staticTexts.elementBoundByIndex(1)

And never get an actual value.  I keep getting:

Optional()

And unwrapping it as a String gives me an empty string

Comment: Turned out I ultimately was not chaining XCUIElementQueries correctly for the UI hierarchy.  Btw, your site is really helpful.  Thanks for running it.  I've been keeping up with it for a little while before this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract some states for example, accessibilityIdentifier, isHitable, value or whatever but, unfortunately you cannot set/change any of these. So apparently you cannot detect if an XCUIElement is already tapped or not. Thats a big limitation in ui test fw.

Answer (score -1):

Joe was sorta on to the right answer but he left out how to actually get the values for the properties he specified.

Lets assume I want to get the string that gets printed for the nav bar of my app

[image]

What I did was I created a XCUIElement for my nav bar:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *navBarTitle = [app.navigationBars elementBoundByIndex:0];
```

I then put a breakpoint after the creation of the navBarTitle object and used the debug console to print out the details of the navBarTitle object:

[image: print out]

You see in the print out of the debug console that there is a **key** called ***identifier***.

To extract that string from that object, I created an NSString object using the following method:

```
NSString *nameofuser = [navBarTitle valueForKey:@"identifier"];
```

I used the XCUIElement navBarTitle and then used the method **valueForKey**. valueForKey extracts the string value for the key identifier.

You can read up about this method here:
[NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1657268-nskeyvaluecoding?language=objc)

valueForKey is the KEY to unlocking the answer to this question....pun intended :)